# Get beans that where created dynamically

Tags: java, spring

Im using `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` to create beans at runtime based on entries in a database. **How would I go about it getting to these beans later in the program?**

I have the id's of the beans and have tried using the `getBeans` method but that returns a beanDefinition instead of the object.

I am trying to use a factory for instantiation passing in the id's of the beans.

Comment: You tried ApplicationContext.getBean("beanName")?

Comment: ApplicationContext.getBean("beanName") get the beanDefinition and trying to cast it to the right type of object gives a castingException

Comment: Why do you even need to create a spring bean dynamically? Why not create a repository class bean that locates these objects?

Comment: Thatsn was the approach i took in the end, the idea behind the beans was that I has singleton objects that can be called at anytime. Now I have them in an static collection that can easily be called from anywhere in the application.